# to find even odd and plain series in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, numeric

this might be naive but I want to know is there any way possible to find rows which have even entries and which have odd.
I have data in this format

```
"41,43,45,49,35,39,47,37"
"12,14,18,16,20,24,22,10"
"1,2,3,4,5,6"
"1,7,521,65,32"
```

what I have tried is to split these values with an Id column and then reading them with Even and Odd functions but it is too time taking.
is there a query or a function through I can find out that which of the rows are even, odd sequence and arbitrary?

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is one way to learn about normalization.

Comment: I think, postgresql does not have even and odd functions. Are you using a framework? can you post your code?

Comment: Use the modulo to find out if a value is even or odd. To check if 41 is odd:  SELECT (41 % 2) = 1;

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your table has some way of (uniquely) identifying each of those lists, this should work:

```
create table data (id integer, list text);

insert into data 
values
(1, '41,43,45,49,35,39,47,37'),
(2, '12,14,18,16,20,24,22,10'),
(3, '1,2,3,4,5,6'),
(4, '1,7,521,65,32');


with normalized as (
  select id, unnest(string_to_array(list,',')::int[]) as val
  from data
)
select id, 
       bool_and((val % 2) = 0) as all_even,
       bool_and((val % 2) <> 0) as all_odd
from normalized
group by id;
```

Not sure if that is fast enough for your needs